# Comparing using rather

Tags: syntax

Suppose I want to say

> Follow this book not me

Would it be the right if the sentence was

> Follow this book rather me

Comment: The idiom "Go by the book" is more common than "follow the book".  It means to do exactly what the rules tell you.  Follow the book, not  me. Follow the book rather than me.

Comment: For the first phrase you need a comma (a pause if spoken): "Follow this/Go by the book, not me", if your meaning is as @Khan commented.

Answer (score 5):

The word "rather", in the sense of *"instead of"* requires a preposition to link it to the next word or sentence, which is **than**, so your sentence would be

> Follow this book rather **than** me